# MS Office thread from a single DLL file?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office

I work for a service desk, we use MS Office on Windows 7. I've noticed that when one office program crashes and if another one is running, closing the other running office program will allow you to relaunch the one that crashed, if you don't close it, it seems that it doesn't work.

For example:

Lets say your Outlook application crashes and you have Skype running. If you try to relaunch Outlook most of the time you'll receive an error saying something along the lines of `Cannot open Outlook`. However if you closed Skype and ran Outlook again, Outlook would launch successfully and Skype would also work successfully.

So my question being, does this happen because MS Office threads off the same DLL file? Such as one thread runs one application, and another thread runs another, that would make sense because from what I understand if a thread crashes and another thread is running it won't launch the other thread until the secondary thread has ended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does this happen because MS Office threads off the same DLL file?

Yes, you are right!
The Office "shares" some DLLs with other programs or (better to say) other applications use several Office' DLLs. A DLL is a kind of "server" that offers its functions to many "clients".

Comment: So would there be a way to reopen the application without having to restart the threads?

Comment: This depends. If only one instance is allowed, you will not be able: The system maintains a per-process reference count on all loaded modules. Calling LoadLibrary increments the reference count. Calling the FreeLibrary or FreeLibraryAndExitThread function decrements the reference count. The system unloads a module when its reference count reaches zero or when the process terminates (regardless of the reference count).